# Mocking axios call in Jest keeps getting caught in catch

Tags: reactjs, axios, jestjs

On load the useEffect in my component calls axios.get to retrieve user data it displays on the page.

I'm trying to replicate this behaviour in jest but I keep falling into the catch and the data key is showing as undefined.

Heres the useEffect from the component I'm testing:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios({
      url: `/user/fav_numbers`,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then(response => {
         // troubleshooting for jest test
        console.log('GET: ', response);
        const { numbers } = response.data;
        setFavNumbers(numbers);
      })
      .catch(response => {
        // troubleshooting for jest test
        console.log('GET error', response);
        setShowError(true);
      });
  }, []);
```

The db returns a object containing a numbers array, each item in the array is an object with an id, user_id, num and reason key, like so:

```
data: { numbers: [ {id: 0, user_id: 1, num: 7, reason: 'traditional lucky number'} ] }
```

This is later presented to the user.

Now heres my Jest test:

```
const mockedResponseDate = {
  numbers: [ { id: 0, user_id:1, 'number: 7, reason: 'test reason' ],
};

const mockResponse = config => {
   // later will need method to test for GET or POST
  const { method, url } = config;
  if (url === '/user/fav_numbers') {
    return {
      status: 200,
      data: mockedResponseDate,
    };
  }
};

jest.mock('packs/axios', () => jest.fn(config => mockResponse(config)));

test('Display initial numbers from db', async () => {
  render(<favNumbers userId={1}/>);

  await waitFor(() => {
    screen.debug();
  });
});
```

When I run this I get the following Network error in the console:

```
config: {
        url: '/user/fav_numbers',
        method: 'get',
        headers: { Accept: 'application/json' },
        transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
        transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
        timeout: 0,
        adapter: [Function: xhrAdapter],
        xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
        maxContentLength: -1,
        maxBodyLength: -1,
        validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
        transitional: {
          silentJSONParsing: true,
          forcedJSONParsing: true,
          clarifyTimeoutError: false
        },
        data: undefined
      },
      request: XMLHttpRequest {},
      response: undefined,
      isAxiosError: true,
      toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
    }
```

I've got absolutely no idea why, so any help would be appreciated.
And let me know if you need anything else, I think I've included all relevant information.

Comment: What is the network error you are getting?

Comment: On a side, might be better to use `nock` to intercept your api calls, rather than trying to mock `axios` manually.

Comment: @RobinThomas Thanks for the comments, the network error is displayed above, with this being a Jest test there isnt anything in the network tab just the console in vs code. I would use nock but this test is part of an existing suite of tests so I'd have to update them all for consistency sake.

Comment: Possible to create a minimum reproducible github repo having this issue? Will be easier for me to debug.

Comment: @RobinThomas thanks for your help mate, I've got a work around for this that I'll add as the answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

This isnt technically a fix but it has resulted in the code working and providing me with the expected results.

So instead of creating a mock response object I've simply used the .mockReturnedValue({}) function then passing the data, error and loading state in that.

Its not exactly what I wanted as its less realistic but it does mean my tests pass now and I can work on getting this other way of testing running.